# Why does Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition intellisense not see ARM "apiVersion": "2016-03-30" for virtualMachines?

Tags: intellisense, azure-resource-manager, visual-studio-2015

Using `Visual Studio 2015 Community edition` it flags an error for the below:

```
{
     "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
     "name": "[variables('VMNamejumpBox')]",
     "location": "[parameters('resourceLocation')]",
     "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
...
```

It gives message:

```
Value must be one of the following values: "2015-05-01-preview","2015-06-15"
```

But I know 2016-03-30 is available:

```
((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute -Location "Australia East").ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq virtualMachines).ApiVersions
2016-03-30
2015-06-15
2015-05-01-preview
```

I want to use the intellisense so for now, I can just use "2015-06-15" and miss out on the latest, but how does Visual Studio get the updates?

I note that I am coming across this issue the same date as the apiVersion 2016-03-30 so perhaps something has not been updated yet for Visual Studio to call out to online?

Comment: the azuredeploy.json template I am using as this at the top:                    {            "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#", }

Comment: I see for "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" the intellisense still only picks up 2015-05-01-preview and 2015-06-15, despite powershell indicating 2016-01-01 being available as well: {((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage -Location "Australia East").Res
ourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq storageAccounts).ApiVersions
2016-01-01
2015-06-15
2015-05-01-preview}

Answer (score 1):

The schemas have not been updated yet to support that apiVersion, the best thing to do in the short term is to use an older one (as you have) and file an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/issues

Once it's updated, you can right-click on the json doc in the editor and select "Reload Schemas" (then close and re-open the file).  The schemas are cached, that will refresh the cache immediately instead of waiting for it to expire.

In general, you should never need to update the schema property of the template file. The schemas for the resource providers are sub-schemas and when they are refreshed they are picked up via the top level schema.